# Jquery menu associated with several divs

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

Hey I have a menu(with JQuery) in a div on the left, with all the links opening in the same div on the right.

All my links work, and they open their new divs respectively, but how do I make it so that once 1 div is clicked, I can change its CSS values (similar to a:visted), like a real menu.

For example, if I have:

A 
B 
C

as my links. I want it so that on clicking on A, A will become underscored. And when clicking on B, the underscore from A will disappear and one will appear under B.

Cheers,

Jeremy

Comment: What mark-up? What current script are you using? What have you tried? What effort have you put into solving this yourself?

Comment: I haven't done anything besides a few google searches, in which resulting me not thinking that this was particularly possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

CSS

```
.CurrentLink {text-decoration: underline; color: red;}
```

Javascript

```
var currentLink;
$(#MenuItem).click(function (){
    if(currentLink){
        currentLink.css('');}
    currentLink = $(this);
    $(this).css('CurrentLink');
}
```

Comment: I may not have mentioned that I am rather new to Jquery.

Comment: and I'm still yet to understand how your code works. How do I implement and modify your code?

Comment: If you can post some sample code, I  will be better able to help beyond this.